# Nginx URL rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, laravel-5

I have a website that has laravel setup to run under `http://www.example.com/lara/`
So, most Laravel pages have URLs of type `http://www.example.com/lara/page/23` OR `http://www.example.com/lara/category/23` etc.

Nginx is the underlying server and it has the following configuration to handle these requests:

```
location /lara/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /lara/index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Everything works ok.

Now, I need to setup a special page with the URL `http://www.example.com/mystuff/` which actually is handled by
`http://www.example.com/lara/category/29`

To get this working I added the following rewrite right below `location /lara/`, that is:

```
rewrite ^/mystuff/(.*)$ /lara/category/29/$1 last;
```

**Unfortunately, I get a page not found error. Any insights?**

**Further investigation & research:**

1)

```
location /mystuff/ {
return 301 /lara/index.php/category/29; 
}
```

worked although that's not (browser address bar changes to) what I actually want.

2) Looks like Laravel is not seeing the updated `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: What if you place it above the `location /lara/` block?

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried that as well and resulted in a page not found error.

Comment: Does `/lara/category/23/` (with the trailing slash) work?

Comment: @RichardSmith `/lara/category/23` doesn't reach Laravel at all where as the one with trailing slash does reach Laravel and results in a 404 thrown by Laravel.

Comment: Does it work if you change `last` to `redirect`?

Comment: @RichardSmith `location /mystuff/ {
                return 301 /lara/index.php/category/29;
        }` worked although that's not (browser address bar changes to) what I actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/lara/(.*)\..*$ $1/mystuff last;
    return  403;
    ...
}
```